# (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3:

Tags: python-3.x

This is the file, It's in the same folder and works fine in VS Code but not in the python IDLE.

```
logged = json.load(open('Logged.txt'))
```

The file has an empty dictionary. `{}`

I have checked some solutions, Some of them said to put 'r' but it doesn't work though and the Path is without any backslashes.

Comment: worked fine when i used jupyter notebook....which idle are you using?

Comment: It works fine in everything, I am just getting ERROR in python idle. This is a college project though and I am sure they will use the IDLE.

Comment: @Karan Are you using windows?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM it seems he is

Comment: Yes, bro, I am using windows.

Comment: is it possible the file is saved with BOM (byte order mark)? Notepad sometimes adds that and causes an error parsing as json

Comment: @Karan Even in IDLE it is working fine ......first of all it will be great if you can share the error message....soo we have a better understanding of  the question

Comment: @Karan Can you **copy** and paste the same path you typed in the python IDLE to the windows cmd. There are some situation where there will be a special character prepended to the path, but not visible in IDLE and shows as `?` in windows CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to be an encoding issue. You have a txt file, but it could be in UTF-8 or ANSI or Unicode.

In python 3, the simplest change would be to specify the encoding when you open the file:

`open('Logged.Txt', encoding="utf-8-sig")`

utf-8-sig should handle the presence of a BOM at the beginning of the file. You can also try `encoding="utf-8"` or `encoding="ascii"` or `encoding="mbcs"` (only on windows)

Comment: full list of encodings here https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings